How to remove 'with' from this method
Here is the function in question:
/**
* @el [Element] Target HTML Element 
* @attr [String] attribute to bind
* @match [Object] Result from regex.exec
*/ 
const bindValue = (el, attr, match) => {
  let binding = getBinding(el, attr);

  if (attr === "textContent") {
    let fn = new Function(
      `scope`,
      `with(scope) {
        return ${match[1]}
      }`,
    );

    binding.attrs[attr].bindings.push((ctx, values) => {
      return ctx.replace(match[0], fn(values));
    });
  }
};

So, what this is doing is taking a string from an HTML template for a web component, like:
<div>{{name == 'Homer' ? 'No Homers Allowed" : name}}</div>

and translating it into an executable function within the scope of the component's bound properties and methods.
In order to not re-render the whole template whenever any bound property is set, during the first render I'm tracking which template binding is being rendered, and using getters on the bound properties to keep track of which bindings are calling which properties, so I can call only those bindings again when that property is set.
What that means is that I need the getter functions to run only when they're called from within the function created by the Function constructor, which means that they cannot be passed as individual variables to the Function constructor, otherwise the getters for the whole scope run, instead of just those referenced in the template string.
As far as I know, the with statement is the only way to create local variables from either an Object or Array of values other than eval, which is an even worse way of doing it than by using with. This seems like probably the only legitimate use of with, since it's being used basically to create the scope of a generated function, not replace the scope within an existing function, but it's still deprecated. I'd like to replace it, if possible, but I can't figure out a way to do so without sacrificing either the power or simplicity of the template format.
For context, here's the full code of the web component extension I'm working on which the previous bit is taken from:
class Component extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.__connected__ = false;
    // this.__useShadow__ = false;

    // Binding cache
    this.__bindings__ = [];
    this.__observed__ = {};
    this.__values__ = {};

    this.__children__ = [];

    // Binding utilities
    this.__current_target__ = null;
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return [];
  }

  static get observedProperties() {
    return [];
  }

  listen(key, handle, fn) {
    if (this.__observed__.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      let observers = this.__observed__[key];
      let idx = observers.findIndex((o) => o.el === this && o.attr === handle);

      if (idx === -1) {
        observers.push({
          el: this,
          attr: handle,
          context: "",
          bindings: [
            (context, values) => {
              return fn(values[key]);
            },
          ],
        });
      } else {
        observers.splice(idx, 1, {
          el: this,
          attr: handle,
          context: "",
          bindings: [
            (context, values) => {
              return fn(values[key]);
            },
          ],
        });
      }
    }
  }

  unlisten(key, handle, fn) {
    if (this.__observed__.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      let observers = this.__observed__[prop];
      let idx = observers.findIndex((o) => o.el === this && o.attr === handle);

      if (idx !== -1) {
        observers.splice(idx, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    const name = this.tagName.toLowerCase();

    if (!this.__connected__) {
      this.__connected__ = true;

      // if (this.__useShadow__) {
      //   if (typeof __template__ !== "undefined") {
      //     let template = __template__.content.cloneNode(true);

      //     const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
      //     shadowRoot.appendChild(template);
      //   }
      // } else {

      this.__children__ = [...this.children];
      if (!!ComponentRegistry.templates[name]) {
        let template =
          ComponentRegistry.templates[name].content.cloneNode(true);

        this.__parseTemplate__(template);
        this.appendChild(template);
      }

      // console.log(this, this.constructor.observedProperties);
      this.constructor.observedProperties.map((prop) => {
        // if (!this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        this.__observed__[prop] = [];

        var p = {};
        p[prop] = {
          get: () => {
            if (
              this.__current_target__ !== null &&
              this.__observed__.hasOwnProperty(prop)
            ) {
              let { el, attr, context, bindings } = this.__current_target__;
              let observers = this.__observed__[prop];
              let idx = observers.findIndex(
                (o) => o.el === el && o.attr === attr,
              );

              if (idx === -1) {
                observers.push({ ...this.__current_target__ });
              } else {
                observers.splice(idx, 1, { ...this.__current_target__ });
              }
            }

            return this.__values__[prop];
          },
          set: (value) => {
            if (value !== this.__values__[prop]) {
              this.__values__[prop] = value;

              let observers = this.__observed__[prop] || [];
              let len = observers.length;

              let values = this.__get_values__();
              for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                let { el, attr, context, bindings } = observers[i];

                for (let i = 0; i < bindings.length; i++) {
                  context = bindings[i](context, values);
                }

                el[attr.replace(":", "")] = context;

                if (!["array", "object"].includes(typeof context)) {
                  if (!!el.setAttribute) {
                    el.setAttribute(attr.replace(":", ""), context);
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
        };

        try {
          Object.defineProperties(this, p);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log("Error defining properties", e);
        }
        // } else {
        //   console.log("Already exists?", this[prop]);
        // }
      });

      Object.keys(this.__observed__).map((key) => {
        if (this.hasAttribute(key)) {
          this[key] = this.getAttribute(key);
        }
      });

      this.__render__();

      if (!!this.connected) {
        this.connected();
      }
    }
  }

  __parseTemplate__(template) {
    const eventExp = /\@([a-z|A-Z]+)/;
    const attrExp = /\:([a-z|A-Z]+)/;
    const boundExp = /\{\{(.*?)\}\}/g;

    const getBinding = (el, attr) => {
      let binding = this.__bindings__.find((b) => b.el === el);
      if (!binding) {
        binding = {
          el: el,
          attrs: {},
        };

        this.__bindings__.push(binding);
      }

      if (!binding.attrs[attr]) {
        let context = el[attr];
        if (!!el.getAttribute) {
          context = el.getAttribute(attr);
        }

        binding.attrs[attr] = {
          context: context,
          bindings: [],
        };
      }

      return binding;
    };

    const bindValue = (el, attr, match) => {
      let binding = getBinding(el, attr);

      if (attr === "textContent") {
        let fn = new Function(
          "scope",
          `
          with(scope) {
            return ${match[1]}
          }`,
        );

        binding.attrs[attr].bindings.push((ctx, values) => {
          return ctx.replace(match[0], fn(values));
        });
      }
    };

    const bindAttribute = (el, attr, context) => {
      let binding = getBinding(el, attr);

      let fn = new Function(
        "scope",
        `
        with(scope) {
          return ${context}
        }`,
      );

      binding.attrs[attr].bindings.push((ctx, values) => {
        return fn(values);
      });
    };

    const bindEvent = (el, attr, context) => {
      let fn = new Function(
        "scope",
        `          
        with(scope) {
          return ${context}
        }`,
      );

      el.addEventListener(attr.replace("@", ""), (e) => {
        let values = this.__get_values__();

        values["$event"] = e;

        fn(values);
      });
    };

    const walk = (el) => {
      let attrs = [...(el.attributes || [])];
      let children = [...(el.childNodes || [])];

      if (el.nodeType === 3) {
        let match;
        while ((match = boundExp.exec(el.textContent)) !== null) {
          bindValue(el, "textContent", match, el.textContent);
        }
      } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
          if (attrExp.test(attrs[i].name)) {
            bindAttribute(el, attrs[i].name, attrs[i].value);
            // el.setAttribute(attrs[i].name.replace(":", ""), attrs[i].value);
          }

          if (eventExp.test(attrs[i].name)) {
            bindEvent(el, attrs[i].name, attrs[i].value);
            // el.setAttribute(attrs[i].name);
          }
        }
      }

      children.map((c) => {
        walk(c);
      });
    };

    walk(template);
  }

  __get_values__() {
    let values = {};

    let methods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(
      Object.getPrototypeOf(this),
    ).filter((method) => {
      return typeof this[method] === "function";
    });

    let keys = Object.keys(this.__observed__);
    let callable = [...keys, ...methods];

    for (let i = 0; i < callable.length; i++) {
      if (typeof this[callable[i]] === "function") {
        Object.defineProperty(values, callable[i], {
          get: () => {
            return this[callable[i]].bind(this);
          },
        });
      } else {
        Object.defineProperty(values, callable[i], {
          get: () => {
            return this[callable[i]];
          },
        });
      }
    }

    return values;
  }

  __render__() {
    let values = this.__get_values__();

    for (var i = 0; i < this.__bindings__.length; i++) {
      let binding = this.__bindings__[i];
      let el = binding.el;

      for (let attr in binding.attrs) {
        let { context, bindings } = binding.attrs[attr];

        this.__current_target__ = { el, attr, context, bindings };

        for (let i = 0; i < bindings.length; i++) {
          context = bindings[i](context, values);
        }

        el[attr.replace(":", "")] = context;

        if (!["array", "object"].includes(typeof context)) {
          if (!!el.setAttribute) {
            el.setAttribute(attr.replace(":", ""), context);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    this.__current_target__ = null;
  }
}


Can’t be done without changing the code (other than very bad ideas like defining properties on the global object, with or without creating new realms each time). Some template engines rewrite free variables to property accesses. I would recommend implementing or using an existing template language that doesn’t allow arbitrary JavaScript – magic is overrated.

This looks clever, maybe it helps.

why can't you just use values[match[1]]? there seems to be no point to with and a dynamic function, unless match[1] is more than a key; a whole dot-path. If it's a path, you can use a resolver function with [].reduce() instead of eval/Function to "drill" into the path. that aside, if you can live with the perf of the de-op'd routine, there's no reason you have to get rid of the with...

@dandavis the expressions can be and little code snippet, which is why defining the scope is important. Can you talk more about how you would use resolvers to solve this issue? I don't quite see it.

Ahh, well if it has expressions then simpler methods won't work. I would still use eval() over Functions though, for speed, security, and simplicity. Functions live in the global scope, whereas eval() is local, and since it's local, you don't need to re-construct the lexical scope or use with. You can also create "better" functions with eval() then Function because you can use closure and a one-time with() outside of the function you're creating, and the magic link persists to/from the function's body code; think with(a){x=[fn1(){},fn2(){},...]}
